# error when using createEntityTables

Tags: magento

I get this error when I include 
$installer->createEntityTables( $this->getTable('red/red') );

I am using enterprise 1.11
I have also seen alternative to that is type every thing which is really time consuming. Could someone please tell me who to make this function work.

```
    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [xdebug_message] => ( ! ) Mage_Eav_Exception: Can't create table: red_faqs_eavexample in C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\Mage.php on line 549
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0003690528{main}(  )..\index.php:0
20.00271167384Mage::run(  )..\index.php:81
30.01012776112Mage_Core_Model_App->run(  )..\Mage.php:640
40.02304545784Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules(  )..\App.php:338
50.46364871080Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates(  )..\App.php:412
60.528411772936Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates(  )..\Setup.php:235
70.528611769664Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb(  )..\Setup.php:327
80.528611769824Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb(  )..\Setup.php:421
90.529511778144include( 'C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\local\Magelocal\Red\sql\red_setup\install-0.1.0.php' )..\Setup.php:624
100.529711778712Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup->createEntityTables(  )..\install-0.1.0.php:6

)
Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\local\Magelocal\Red\sql\red_setup\install-0.1.0.php" - Can't create table: red_faqs_eavexample

#0 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '0.1.0')
#2 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('0.1.0')
#3 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\app\Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\ubt.onlocal.com.au\index.php(81): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with an error being triggered when it shouldn't be. Long story short, MySQL doesn't support DDL transactions, and in the course of the method DDL routines are being found in the SQL and an error is thrown.

The easy answer is to comment out this line:

---

**lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/PDO/Mysql.php**

```
protected function _checkDdlTransaction($sql)
{
    if (is_string($sql) && $this->getTransactionLevel() > 0) {
        $startSql = strtolower(substr(ltrim($sql), 0, 3));
        if (in_array($startSql, $this->_ddlRoutines)) {
            // comment this out: trigger_error(Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::ERROR_DDL_MESSAGE, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so allows your module to install. Obviously hacking a core file is a terrible idea. You should extend the method or allow the SQL to run, and then translate the generated SQL into the Magento MySQL API, as seen in core sql setup scripts. The latter is a major pain.. the better idea would be to extend the method.

[More here](http://zaclee.net/magento/magento-1-7-custom-module-setup-createentitytables-method-fails) on background information and troubleshooting.